# Animate change in contentInset while scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to mimic the url-bar hiding animation similar to Safari. For this, I set a `contentInset` to the `scrollView`, and change this `contentInset's` top and bottom value as I scroll. But I couldn't get it to work flawlessly. I observed that the `scrollView` jumps while setting its contentInset.

Can anyone help me with this problem and provide me with a sample code to achieve the same?

Comment: You can try changing frame of the control directly.

Comment: @Yogi :In the case of webView, the webPage bounces while changing the frame.

Comment: You can turn off bouncing of scroll view. Locate scroll view from the subviews of web view and set its bouncing to NO